# Why do we use optional in PAM even if it'll be ignored?

Tags: linux, authentication, pam

As we know, `optional` is one of the control value in PAM's configuration files.

From [linux-pam.org](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-configuration-file.html):

> **optional:**
>   the success or failure of this module is only important if it is the only module in the stack associated with this service+type.

I'm confused.

Here's the `/etc/pam.d/login` :

```
session    required     pam_selinux.so open
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      system-auth
session    include      postlogin
-session   optional     pam_ck_connector.so
```

I see two rules with `optional` control with just actions.

I assume we only use `optional` for non-authenticated purpose rules. Is that right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Important note: optional modules won't be ignored, they will be processed, their ***results*** will be ignored, i.e., even if they fail, the authentication process won't be aborted.

There are many situations where you may want an action to be performed (a module to be executed) during authentication but, even in case of fail, you don't want that the authentication process get aborted.

One practical example is if you want to use pam to automatically open a dm-crypt encrypted device during the login using the same password as the user's password:

```
auth optional pam_exec.so expose_authtok quiet /usr/sbin/cryptsetup --allow-discards open UUID=... /home/username
```

Note that if `required` is used instead of `optional` here, the first login will succeed as cryptsetup will return 0 as its exit code, but if the user logs out and then logs in again, the login would fail as the device is already open and cryptsetup will return a non-zero exit code.  Yet, in this case you still would want the login to succeed.

This is just one example that came to my mind because I actually use it, i.e., this is not a theoretical situation, but this is one among many many situations where you want that a failed module won't abort the authentication process.

Answer (score 0):

Other practical uses, in addition to [Marcelo's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/424034/70524):

```
$ grep 'auth.*optional' /etc/pam.d -R
/etc/pam.d/lightdm:auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
/etc/pam.d/lightdm:auth    optional        pam_kwallet.so
/etc/pam.d/lightdm:auth    optional        pam_kwallet5.so
/etc/pam.d/gnome-screensaver:auth optional pam_gnome_keyring.so
/etc/pam.d/login:auth       optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=3000000
/etc/pam.d/login:auth       optional   pam_group.so
/etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter:auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
/etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter:auth    optional        pam_kwallet.so
/etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter:auth    optional        pam_kwallet5.so
/etc/pam.d/unity:auth optional pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

These are all from a Ubuntu 16.04 VM, where I have never touch PAM configuration (except in so far as any packages I installed might have, which is where I suspect the `pam_kwallet*` lines came from).

- The GNOME Keyring and KDE Wallet modules are easy to understand: they unlock your login keyring, where your SSH and GPG keys and your browser passwords maybe saved.
- `pam_faildelay.so` offers an excellent example of an ignored module still providing an immediate, evident feedback: making you wait if you entered the wrong password. Here's a module that you'd usually use as `optional`, since the success or failure really doesn't matter much. But! `pam_faildelay.so` only supports `auth`, so *any* normal use of this would be `auth optional`.